# AJAX reCaptcha Throwing Undocumented Error ("programming_error")

Tags: ajax, recaptcha

I'm trying to use the AJAX version of recaptcha. Recaptcha.create() is working fine, but when I try to use Recaptcha.ajax_verify(), I get a mysterious error back:

```
{
   is_correct: false,
   programming_error: 'Input error: c: Parameter signature was not set'
}
```

Here's a sample HTML file to try it yourself (using your own public key):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/js/recaptcha_ajax.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="recaptcha_target"></div>
<input id="recaptcha_submit" type="button" value="Submit" />
<pre id="recaptcha_response"></pre>
<script>
$(document).ready( function () {
    Recaptcha.create( '**YOUR_PUBLIC_KEY**', 'recaptcha_target', {
        tabindex: 1,
        theme: 'clean',
        callback: Recaptcha.focus_response_field
    });
    $('#recaptcha_submit').click( function () {
        Recaptcha.ajax_verify( function () {
            $('#recaptcha_response').text( 'is_correct: '+arguments[0].is_correct+'\nprogramming_error: '+arguments[0].programming_error );
        });
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Does anyone have a clue what that error is? I looked at a beautified version of the recaptcha code and it looks like Recaptcha.ajax_verify() formats the request for verification on its own. It only takes 1 parm: a callback function. If there's something I'm missing (such as the private key - which I guess should not be in the front-end JS code), I don't see where it would be put.

I realize that I can just write a PHP responder of my own to do the verification with, but I want something completely client-side. From the looks of it, the AJAX version should support such usage.

Comment: In the end, I did whip up my own API responder in PHP. I never did figure out this error.